# Need help creating a parse table view controller

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm trying to create a normal UItableview which, when you click on a cell, it opens up into another view controller and displays information - I got this part down.

How do I get the information that comes up in the next view controller to be parse-based? Meaning that when you click on a cell, what is being displayed after is information being pulled from the parse server. So that way I can just update any information through parse without going through the app directly.

Comment: So the information on the table view isn't coming from Parse? Do you have the Parse iOS SDK setup already?

Comment: Yes, I already have that set up. And no, it's not coming from parse.

Comment: Do you think you could help? I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so it depends what data you need/how you want to fetch it. The example below for example would get all entries from one type of class you have on Parse:

```
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ParseClassYouWantToGet"];
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
        {
            if (!error)
            {
                for (PFObject *object in objects)
                {
                    NSLog(@"%@", object)
                    [parseDict setObject:tmpObject forKey:tmpKey];
                }
                return;
            }
            NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
        }];
```

Do you want to get all the entries? Or all that meet a certain condition? Or just one based on ID? Also check out the [documentation for PFQuery](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html) if you haven't gone through it yet.

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this tutorial which perfectly answers your question](https://medium.com/swift-programming/ios-swift-parse-com-tutorial-set-up-xcode-project-part-2-of-3-31a17d1c6581).

If all you're trying to do is access data stored on Parse, the answer is you need to query for it.

If you are trying to pass the selected Parse object from your table view to the details view controller, you need to create a variable within your details view controller for the selected PFObject which you can set in the table view's `prepareForSegue` method.

Skim through the tutorial and you will have a breeze accomplishing what you want.